# implementation 'com.android.support.recyclerview-v7.27.1.1' FAILED

Tags: java, android-studio, implementation, android-studio-3.0

I am beginner. I have a problem. It is said that:

> Exception is:
> org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Caused by: org.gradle.api.IllegalDependencyNotation: Supplied String module notation 'com.android.support.recyclerview-v7.27.1.1' is invalid.

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
```

}

android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.telegramstickermaker"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support.appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support.recyclerview-v7.27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.design-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:4.1.0'
implementation 'info.androidhive:imagefilters:1.0.7'
```

}

Comment: I think you have a typo on your dependency: `implementation 'com.android.support.recyclerview-v7.27.1.1'` should be `implementation 'com.android.support.recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'`. Note that the difference is that there is a semi-colon.